Is there such thing as too many subdivisions/geometry for cloth sims?
I want to make a flag in Blender using cloth sims and I’m wondering if there’s such thing as too many subdivisions and geometry for cloth sim, other then the bake time and hardware.
I mean just wen it comes to how the sim would look, like instead of improving we get diminishing returns, and it actually starts looking worse as you add geometry.
Again I mean is there such thing as too much when it comes to how the sun turns out and looks and not processing power?

The more subdivisions before cloth modifier the more potential for wrinkles. Also stability decreases because it's all floating-point calculations, and that has limited precision, so as points get closer, stuff becomes more quirky. Also from a practical perspective, a low poly object will be stiff and resistant to bending (as an edge is always straight), and as you subdivide it may be hard to fine-tune bending/shearing resistances to get the same effect.

Imo, yes.  Start with simpler geometry, run your sim, and then subdivide afterwards to round it out

There's also a big problem with self collision distance value, that can't be less than 0.001, so when the mesh is too dense this value gets too high, leading to instability. That's why we often have to scale up our models before simulations.

There's a big problem with self collision distance value, that can't be less than 0.001, so when the mesh is too dense this value gets too high, leading to instability. That's why we often have to scale up our models before simulations.
Generally, if you want simulations on dense geometry, you can build a LoPoly proxy of the model, simulate on the proxy, then use a Mesh Deform modifier to apply the deformations on the HiPoly mesh.

The more subdivisions before cloth modifier the more potential for wrinkles. Also stability decreases because it's all floating-point calculations, and that has limited precision, so as points get closer, stuff becomes more quirky. Also from a practical perspective, a low poly object will be stiff and resistant to bending (as an edge is always straight), and as you subdivide it may be hard to fine-tune bending/shearing resistances to get the same effect.
